# Filtering AutoQuery Results to Only Display Table Rows that Match Data in the Users Session

Tags: database, servicestack, multi-tenant, servicestack-autoquery, autoquery-servicestack

I'm working on a project that want's to control data access in a multi-tenant system. I've got a table set up which has a row on it that says what tenant the object applies to. Let's call this property

```
ClientObject.ClientOrgId
```

I want to set *something* up so that anytime this table is accessed the only results that are returned are results that match some piece of data in the users session. I.e.

```
ClientObject.ClientOrgId == UserSession.ClientOrgId
```

and I ideally want to do this restriction on the table model instead of re-implementing it for every query created.

I've found the [Autofilter attribute](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-crud#autofilter) in the service stack documentation, and it looks like the thing that I want to use, but I've been unable to get it working. An example of my code is below, and I'm not seeing any filtering whenever I set the user sessions ClientOrgID to anything different.

```
[Authenticate]
[Route("/clientObject", HttpMethods.Post)]
[Api("Creates a Client Object")]
public class CreateClientObject : ICreateDb<ClientObjectTableModel>, IReturn<ClientObjectMutationResponse>
{
    [ValidateNotEmpty]
    public string ClientName{ get; set; }

    [ValidateNotEmpty]
    public string ClientLocation { get; set; }

    [ValidateNotEmpty]
    [ValidateNotNull]
    public Guid? ClientOrgId { get; set; }
}

[AutoFilter(QueryTerm.Ensure, nameof(ClientObjectTableModel.ClientOrgId), Eval= "userSession.ClientOrgId")]
public class ClientObjectTableModel : AuditBase
{
    [AutoId]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ClientName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ClientLocation { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid ClientOrgId { get; set; }
}
```

I even went off the rails and tried something like

```
[AutoFilter(QueryTerm.Ensure, nameof(ClientObjectTableModel.ClientLocation), Value = "The Fourth Moon Of Mars")]
```

with the expectation that nothing would get returned, and yet I'm still seeing results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All [AutoQuery CRUD Attribute](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-crud#autoquery-crud-attributes) like `[AutoFilter]` should be applied to the AutoQuery Request DTO, not the data model.

Have a look at how to [populate Tenant Ids with AutoPopulate](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-crud#autopopulate) and how it's later used to filter results with `[AutoFilter]`.